# How do you count the number of literals in a boolean function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

Let $f(X,Y,Z) = XYZ + XY'Z' + X'YZ'$
and $g(X,Y,Z) = XY + X'Y'Z'$

What is the number of literals in each of these expressions?

I think there are 9 literals in $f(X,Y,Z)$ and 5 literals in $g(X,Y,Z)$. But am I counting them correctly?

If not, do you not count the same variable twice within the same expression?
In that case it would be 6 literals in $f(X,Y,Z)$. And 5 literals in $g(X,Y,Z)$.

Thanks.

Comment: You are counting correctly (9 and 5, as you said.)  If you were counting _distinct_ literals it would be 3 and 3. $X'$ is not a literal, it is the complement of the expression $X$.